# Do joists need to be attached to the beam they're resting on?

Tags: joists, structural

Installed a 2 x12 x10 header opening that supports the above floor joists. Wanted to know if the header needs to be toenailed to each joist resting on it?

Comment: I would consider using metal ties.

Comment: Hi Gerald, welcome to our site. Your question will need some additional information about what you are trying to achieve. A photo or two may help as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Code (See ICC Table 2304.9.1) requires joists toenailed into beams by:

1. 3 - 8d common nails, or
2. 3 - 10d box nails, or
3. 3 - 3” x 0.131” nails, or
4. 3 - 14 ga. Staples with 7/16” crown.

Answer (score 2):

There are metal brackets you can use when you dont have the space to nail it. Also palm-nailer are cheap and a good way to get into tight places. And yes they need to be nailed down.